# "arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')" returning "OSError"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, oserror

I'm new to Python. I try to access my 'current' project but I keep getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 344, in __init__
    self._arc_object = arcgisscripting._mapping.ArcGISProject(*gp_fixargs((aprx_path,), True))
OSError: CURRENT
```

I tried using upper and lower case single and double quote.

Here is the 1st part of my code.

```py
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your trace back, it appears you're calling this from `test.py`, which I'd guess means you're calling a file OUTSIDE ArcGIS Pro (you're calling the script from command line or an IDE). **The** `CURRENT` **keyword *only* works when you're inside ArcGIS Pro**. It does not work outside the app, like when you're calling from command line or in an IDE. In those cases, you need a full path to the `.APRX`

The only time you can use `CURRENT` is if calling from the Python window, or a script tool inside ArcGIS Pro.